How to add a JSONB field to the FOS Elastic index
I have a table in PostgreSQL user that has a data (JSONB) field that stores this structure
   {
         "user_info": {
              "first_name": "Dan",
              ...
         }
    }

The entity looks like this
class User {
    private array $userInfo;
    
    public function setUserInfo(array $userInfo)
    {
        $this->userInfo = $userInfo;
    }
    
    public function getUserInfo(): array
    {
        return $this->userInfo;
    }
}

I want to add the first_name each of user field to the elasticsearch index using the FOS Elasticsearch bundle
What should this index look like from the fos_elastic.yaml config?
